# Conflict: terminated by setWebhook request Telegraf (Telegram Bot) and MenuBuilder (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, webhooks, telegram-bot

briefly, so I built a telegram bot on node js with the Telegraf library. My bot uses menu builder provided by the telegram app, but if a new user enters my bot the menu wont appear until I enable the menu builder webhook. And when I enable it , my node js script crashes and gives this error:

```
 (node:26284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 409: Conflict: terminated by setWebhook request
```

Any help in this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you run multiple instances of your bot?